# Does locally Lipschitz imply Lipschitz on closed balls?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, lipschitz-functions

I was wondering whether a real valued function on the space $C$ of continuous real functions (defined on a closed interval $[a,b]$)
i.e.
$$
C= \mathcal{C}([a,b];\mathbb{R}^d)
$$
which is locally Lipschitz is also Lipschitz in sets as
$$
A:=\{ f \in C : || f ||_{\infty} \leq k \}
$$
or
$$
B:=\{ f \in C : || f -g||_{\infty} \leq k \}
$$
for some $k>0$ and some continuous function $g \in C$.
As I found out here:
[Compact sets in uniform norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2615017/compact-sets-in-uniform-norm)
compactness can't be used.

P.S. With a real valued function on the space $C$ I mean
$$
G\colon C \to \mathbb{R}^d
$$

Comment: It depends on the meaning of "operator": If it is linear, then yes, if nonlinear, then no.

Comment: @MoisheCohen, of course non linear, have you ever a seen non-Lipschitz, linear operator?
Can you show that in the non-linear case the answer is no?

Comment: Yes, I had seen plenty of non-Lip linear operators (of course, unbounded ones).

Comment: @MoisheCohen, thank you for the answer, I realized my concern wasn't about an operator but about a real valued function. You can now see my edit.

Comment: note that linear operators  are  continuous (bounded) if and only if they are lipschitz on closed balls

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ be any infinite-dimensional Banach space, $B=B(0,1)\subset V$ the closed unit ball.  Take a countably-infinite subset $E\subset B$ such that the distance between distinct points in $E$ is $> 2r>0$. Consider the disjoint closed balls $B(x_i,r)$ centered at the points $x_i\in E$. For each $i$ define a function $f_i: V\to {\mathbb R}$ supported on $B(x_i,r)$ whose Lipshitz constant on this ball equals $i$. Lastly, set
$$
f:= \sum_{i=1}^\infty f_i.
$$
This function will be locally Lipschitz on $V$ but not Lipschitz on the ball $B(0,1+r)$.

Comment: Could you show the existence of infinite functions with norm (infinite norm) smaller than 1 such that the distance between any two of them is greater than 2r?

Comment: @ThePunisher: This is a simple negation of compactness for a complete metric space: A complete metric space (such as the unit ball $B$) is compact if and only if it is totally bounded. What I wrote is the negation of total boundedness. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_bounded_space

Comment: @ThePunisher: If you want an explicit sequence, take non-negative functions $g_i$ on $[0,1]$; each $g_i$ is supported on $[1/(i+1), 1/i]$ and has maximum equal to $1$ at on that interval. Then $||g_i-g_j||=1$ whenever $i\ne j$.